# Bind header checkbox with DataTrigger Style

Tags: wpf, checkbox, datatrigger

I have a datagrid with a checkbox column in hearer and in the body. When the header is checked I want to check all the checkbox rows..Its not working right now..please help..

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                       <CheckBox Name="chkHeaderExtract"></CheckBox>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <CheckBox x:Name="chkExtract" IsChecked="{Binding TaskDetails[0].IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
                               <CheckBox.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                                       <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chkHeaderExtract,Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                               <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding ElementName=chkHeaderExtract,Path=IsChecked}"></Setter>
                                           </DataTrigger>
                                       </Style.Triggers>
                                   </Style>
                               </CheckBox.Style>
                           </CheckBox>

                       </DataTemplate>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Can users select items individually without selecting all or none? Typically in these scenarios, I just add a Click event to the header checkbox to loop through all items in the DataGrid and check or uncheck them. The checkboxes in individual rows have their .Checked value bound to the data item behind the row.

Comment: Hey Rachel could you please write simple code for accomplishing this.

Comment: I don't have time to write it up right now, but do a google search on something like "WPF check all header and you should find plenty of examples. Depending on if you're using the MVVM design pattern or not, just pick the solution that works for you. Basic idea is the same though - using the header checkbox checked event, either call a viewmodel command to check/uncheck everything or loop through `DataGrid.ItemsSource` and set the property bound to CheckBox.Checked of each item